How to fix : Subscription listener is not a function when turning off the location GPS?
how to fix Subscription listener is not function when I turning off the location GPS, To be honest I don't know what kind of error is this and why this error show when I turn off the GPS location.
Task: Saving battery life via turning off the Location
Current Problem: Subscription listener is not function
Pic for attention
Goal: If I start watchPosition and try to turning off the GPS location this subscription listener is not function will not prompt as error.
useEffect(() => {
    watchPosition()
    return () => {
        Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId)
    }
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    requestLocationPermission()
    return () => null
}, [])


const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        const auth = await Geolocation.requestAuthorization("whenInUse");
        if (auth === "granted") {
            // updateCurrentLocation()
            return true
        }
    } else {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
                'title': 'Project Driver App',
                'message': 'Project Driver access to your location '
            }
        )
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            // updateCurrentLocation()
            return true
        }
    }
}

const updateCurrentLocation = async () => {
    
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (location) => {
            mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion({
                longitude: location?.coords?.longitude,
                latitude: location?.coords?.latitude,
                latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
                longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta,
            }, 1000);
            dispatch(DriverCurrentCoordinates({
                current_lat:location?.coords?.latitude,
                current_long:location?.coords?.longitude
            }))
            setCurrentCoordinate([location?.coords?.latitude, location?.coords?.longitude])
        },
        (error) => {
            if(error.message == 'No location provider available.') {
                // navigation.navigate('Home')
                // Geolocation.stopObserving()
            }
            console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 0 }
    );
}

const watchPosition = async () => {
    watchId.current = Geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        if(position?.coords?.accuracy < 50) {
            setCurrentCoordinate([position?.coords?.latitude, position?.coords?.longitude])
            mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion({
                latitude: position?.coords?.latitude,
                longitude: position?.coords?.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
                longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta,
            },1000)
        }
    }, {
    }, { enableHighAccuracy: true,maximumAge: 0})
}

Thank you.
